# How to continue to loop and create new cell based on arraylist

Tags: java, excel, loops, apache-poi, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a string arraylist name as code like this:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

and another string arraylist that contain data like this name as DWS:

```
[a11,a22,a33,a44,a55,a66,a77,b11,b22,b33,b44,b55,b66,b77,c11,c22,c33,c44,c55,c66,c77,d11,d22,d33,d44,d55,d66,d77]
```

What I want to do is I want to write to the DWS arraylist into excel file like this:

[image]

I have tried this way:

```
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File(namefile));
    XSSFWorkbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb1.getSheetAt(0);

        int limit = 7;
        for (int m = 0; m < code.size(); m++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < DWS.size(); x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                    Row row2 = sheet1.getRow(i + 2);
                    Cell cell = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);
                    cell.setCellValue(DWS.get(x));
                }
            }
        }
```

but the result that I get is:
[image]

Any idea how to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE**

I change my code like this as suggested:

```
int limit = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        Row row2 = sheet1.getRow(i + 2);
        for (int m = 0; m < code.size(); m++) {
            Cell cell = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);
            cell.setCellValue(DWS.get(i));
        }
    }
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

It only loop the first 7 data. I need it to continue for the rest of the arraylist. like the first image.

**UPDATE**

let me explain again the flow of my code

1) It will loop the DWS arraylist into the first cell which is cell no 5 and loop until the last row which row no 7,

2) then , after it reach row no 7, it then supposedly create a new cell which in line `Cell cell = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);`and then again, continue looping from the DWS arraylist data.

3) this steps will continue until it reach the last arraylist data of DWS

is that possible to do that?

**UPDATE 2.0**

I change to this:

```
int cellValueIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        Row row2 = sheet1.getRow(i + 2);
        for (int m = 0; m < code.size(); m++) {
            Cell cell = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);
            cell.setCellValue(DWS.get(cellValueIndex));
            cellValueIndex++;
        }
    }
```

but I got error like this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

**UPDATE 3.0**

I change to this but the result is still wrong

```
int cellValueIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        Row row2 = sheet1.getRow(i + 2);
        for (int m = 0; m < code.size(); m++) {
            Cell cell = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);
            cell.setCellValue(DWS.get(cellValueIndex));
        }
        cellValueIndex = cellValueIndex + 1;
    }
```

[image]

**UPDATE 4.0**

I have change to this:

```
    int cellValueIndex = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        Row row2 = sheet1.getRow(i + 2);
        Cell cell = row2.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue(DWS.get(cellValueIndex));
        cellValueIndex++;

        int x = row2.getRowNum();

        if (x == limit) {

            for (int m = 1; m < code.size(); m++) {
                Cell cell1 = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);
                cell1.setCellValue(DWS.get(cellValueIndex + 1));
                cellValueIndex++;

            }
        }
    }
```

The result is like this:

[image]

But when I try to set the i=0;, like this:

```
int cellValueIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < total1; i++) {
        Row row2 = sheet1.getRow(i + 2);
        Cell cell = row2.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue(DWS.get(cellValueIndex));
        cellValueIndex++;

        int x = row2.getRowNum();

        if (x == total1) {
            i = 0;
            for (int m = 1; m < shiftcode.size(); m++) {
                Cell cell1 = row2.createCell(m * 3 + 4);
                cell1.setCellValue(DWS.get(cellValueIndex));
                cellValueIndex++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got error like this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: On your UPDATEd version: You are still not using cellValueIndex as I suggested in my answer below. If you use it, your data will be displayed correctly.

Comment: @Ketan I got error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:`

Comment: @Ketan see my latest update

Comment: Your limit is 7, and code has got size 4. So you need 28 elements... and the max value that cellValueIndex should go is 27 (which is the 28th element in array or list). If you have less elements in the DWS then you are bound to get that exception. Otherwise I don't see a reason. Use debug functionality of the IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse and you should be able to do it

Comment: @Ketan see my latest update

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 for loops going on here! However as I see, you are creating cells in the third loop, where the value of the x is the last representational value from the DWS. If DWS is just a source of the cell values then you should have a separate index for that rather than keeping a loop for that.

In this case, though you don't realize from the end result, it is creating DWS.size times tables and it's cells! You don't realize it from the result because what you see is the last executed table which contains the value d77 only. And you are putting ONLY one value to all the cells because in the last loop DWS.get(x) is always constant, you don't have to do that.

You have to put different values to each and every cell.

Solution:
You need just 2 loops.

```
int cellValueIndex = 0;
for (int m = 0; m < limit; m++) {
    // create a row here
    for (int n = 0; n < code.length; n++) {
       // take the value from DWS like DWS.get(cellValueIndex) and 
       // keep incrementing cellValueIndex by one always
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it is code.size() rather than code.length? because I got error like this 'length cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache csv printer you can print rows easily. I wrote a solution for you that work:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class DataGenerator {

    private static final String[] HEADERS = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    private static final String[] DATA = {"a11", "a22", "a33", "a44", "a55", "a66", "a77", "b11", "b22", "b33", "b44", "b55", "b66", "b77", "c11", "c22", "c33", "c44", "c55", "c66", "c77", "d11", "d22", "d33", "d44", "d55", "d66", "d77"};
    private static CSVPrinter csvPrinter;
    private static final CSVFormat getFileCsvFormat = CSVFormat.newFormat(';')
            .withHeader(HEADERS)
            .withRecordSeparator('\n');

    private static final int rowSize = DATA.length / HEADERS.length; // 7


    @BeforeAll
    private static void setupCsv() throws IOException {
        final long date = new Date().getTime();

        final String fileTestData = "src/test/resources/csv/testdata.csv";
        final FileWriter getDataWriter = new FileWriter(fileTestData);
        csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(getDataWriter, getFileCsvFormat);

        System.out.println("Files created:" + fileTestData);
    }

    @Test
    void printCsv() throws IOException {
        final int dataLength = DATA.length;
        final List<String[]> columns = getColumns(DATA);
        final String[][] rows = transformToRows(columns);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            printRow(rows[i]);

        }
        csvPrinter.flush();
    }

    private void printRow(final String[] row) {
        try {
            csvPrinter.printRecord(row);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<String[]> getColumns(final String[] data) {
        final List<String[]> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        final int dataLength = data.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i += rowSize) {
            partitions.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(DATA, i, Math.min(i + rowSize, dataLength)));
        }
        return partitions;
    }

    /**
     * a1 a2
     * b1 b2
     * - transform to: -
     * a1 b1
     * a2 b2
     */
    private String[][] transformToRows(final List<String[]> columns) {
        final String[][] dataMatrix = new String[rowSize][HEADERS.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowSize; j++) {
                //{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}
                dataMatrix[j][i] = columns.get(i)[j];
            }
        }

        return dataMatrix;
    }
```

I think your main problem however was how to transform your data from a column structure to a row structure, which you can print left to right. The input data is split into columns easily, but most csv/excel/... printers work by row. You can use the `transformToRows` method from my example to do this.